# Using random to generate strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

I have code that reads from files of surnames, female and male names and randomly generates a name in the following format: lastname, male/female name.

The files are in the following format:

> JAMES    3.318    4,840,833 1

I have the following working code:

```
def picks(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        lines = [line.strip('\n') for line in f]
        pick = randint(0, len(lines))
    return lines[pick].split()[0]


def random_name(number_of_names):
    nselect = ''
    for _ in range(1, number_of_names+1):
        g = randint(0,1)
        if g==1:
            nselect = picks('femalenames.txt')
        else:
            nselect = picks('malenames.txt')
        print(g)
        print( '{0:s}, {1:s}\n'.format(picks('surnames.txt'), nselect))


random_name(5)
```

The code generates the correct output but I feel the code could be trimmed a bit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your intuition was accurate! Here is a shortened version with (almost-)identical functionality:

```
from random import choice

def picks(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        lines = [line.strip() for line in f]
    return choice(lines).split()[0]    

def random_names(number_of_names):
    for _ in range(number_of_names):
        nselect = picks(choice(('femalenames.txt', 'malenames.txt')))
        print('{0:s}, {1:s}\n'.format(picks('surnames.txt'), nselect))

random_name(5)
```

Note the following:

- `str.strip` removes whitespace (including newlines) by default, so you don't need to make the argument explicit;
- `random.choice` is a neater way to select a random item from a list than generating and using an index;
- `random_names` is a better name for the function, as you can specify a varying number of names;
- You don't need to initialise `nselect`;
- Why carefully adjust an index you *aren't actually using* by one? `0` is the default start for `range`, so we can just use `number_of_names` directly; and
- Selecting directly from the two possible filenames makes the functionality more obvious (although you can no longer `print(g)`, which was a bad name anyway).

Comment: Not worth writing up another answer, but I'd consider memoizing the `picks` function (weakly, if memory is a concern).  Sufficiently large files or desired number of names will make this sluggish if we have to pick every time.

Comment: @jonrsharpe. why is the choice in double brackets?

Comment: @LeonSurrao one set for the call, one set for the tuple to choose from.